# Calling distcp from Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

can anyone tell me what's the most robust way to copy files from HDFS to S3 in Pyspark ?

I am looking at 2 options:

I. Call distcp directly as in the following:

```
  distcp_arglist =['/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop','distcp',
                  ...,
                  '-overwrite',
                   src_path, dest_path]
```

II. Using `s3-distcp` - which seems a bit more involved.
https://gist.github.com/okomestudio/699edbb8e095f07bafcc

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: distcp is a disk copy operation

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to point you at a little bit of my code, [cloudcp](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala)

This is a basic proof of concept of implementing distCp *in spark*

- individual files are scheduled via the spark scheduler; not ideal for 0-byte files, but stops the job being held up by a large file off one node
- does do locality via a special RDD which works out the location of every row (i.e file) differently (which has to be in the org.apache.spark package for scoped access)
- shows how to do FS operations within a spark map
- shuffles the input for a bit of randomness
- collects results within an RDD

Doesn't do: 
* incremental writes (you can't compare checksums between HDFS and S3 anyway, but it could do a check for `fs.exists(path)` before the copy. 
* permissions. S3 doesn't have them
* throttling
* scheduling of the big files first. You ought to.
* recovery of job failure (no incremental, see)

Like I said, PoC to say "we be more agile by using spark for the heavy lifting"

Anyway, take it and play, you can rework it to operate within an existing spark context with ease, as long as you don't mind a bit of scala coding.

Comment: Spark/Mapreduce doen;t play any big role here. It's the game of network and IO. If any code like distcp that work and can scale horizontally, Sure wins this game, By the way DistCp is battle tested.

Comment: distcp is wonderful, but it is optimised for HDFS <---> HDFS copies where each end has the same block size so that incremental updates work. As the person who gets to field distcp & cloud issues, I have to deal where HDFS-centric changes break cloud integration: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-16932

Answer (score 0):

**Distcp** would probably be the way to go as it is well-proven solution for transfering data between the clusters. I guess any possible alternatives would do something similar - create mapreduce jobs for transfering the data. Important point here is how to tune this process for your particular data as it could really depend on many factors like networking or map-reduce settings. I recommend you to read HortonWorks [article](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.3/bk_cloud-data-access/content/distcp-s3-perf.html) about how you can tune this process